# Getting specific key values from JSONB into columns

Tags: postgresql, performance, json, query-performance

In this query `attributes` a JSONB column:

```
select
  COUNT(order_items.attributes) as sayi,
  order_items.attributes
from order_items
  INNER JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.product_id
GROUP BY order_items.attributes
```

I have data like this:

```
[{"name": "Kampanya Seçimi", "value": "USB Çakmaklık (7,99 TL)"}, {"name": "İp, Dikiş Rengi", "value": "Kırmızı"}]
[{"name": "Kampanya Seçimi", "value": "USB Çakmaklık (7,99 TL)"}, {"name": "İp, Dikiş Rengi", "value": "Kırmızı"}]
[{"name": "Kampanya Seçimi", "value": "USB Çakmaklık (7,99 TL)"}, {"name": "İp, Dikiş Rengi", "value": "Kırmızı"}]
```

I would like to specifically names to a column, value to another column. Desired result is to select attribute and put them in 2 columns "name" "value" as column name, and the contents listed under it as rows.

How can I do this? I read a lot of website but I couldn't succeed.

PostgreSQL version: psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1)

`products` table definition:

```
         Column         |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 product_id             | integer                        |           | not null | nextval('products_product_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 display_price          | numeric(8,2)                   |           | not null |                                              | main     |              |
 marketplace_product_id | text                           |           | not null |                                              | extended |              |
 title                  | text                           |           | not null |                                              | extended |              |
 subtitle               | text                           |           |          |                                              | extended |              |
 seller_id              | integer                        |           | not null |                                              | plain    |              |
 deleted_at             | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                              | plain    |              |
 created_at             | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                              | plain    |              |
 updated_at             | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                              | plain    |              |
 images                 | jsonb                          |           |          |                                              | extended |              |
 seller_stock_code      | text                           |           |          |                                              | extended |              |
```

`order_items` table:

```
            Column            |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 order_item_id                | integer                        |           | not null | nextval('order_items_order_item_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 order_id                     | integer                        |           | not null |                                                    | plain    |              |
 marketplace_item_id          | text                           |           | not null |                                                    | extended |              |
 product_id                   | integer                        |           |          |                                                    | plain    |              |
 shipping_fee_type_id         | integer                        |           | not null |                                                    | plain    |              |
 cargo_code                   | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
 seller_coupon_amount         | numeric(8,2)                   |           |          |                                                    | main     |              |
 mall_discount_amount         | numeric(8,2)                   |           |          |                                                    | main     |              |
 item_variety_stock_code      | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
 item_price_without_discounts | numeric(8,2)                   |           |          |                                                    | main     |              |
 invoice_amount               | numeric(8,2)                   |           | not null |                                                    | main     |              |
 quantity                     | integer                        |           | not null |                                                    | plain    |              |
 commision                    | numeric(8,2)                   |           |          |                                                    | main     |              |
 shipping_carrier_id          | integer                        |           |          |                                                    | plain    |              |
 tracking_code                | text                           |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
 shipment_number              | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
 shipment_number_status       | text                           |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
 deleted_at                   | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                                    | plain    |              |
 created_at                   | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                                    | plain    |              |
 updated_at                   | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                                    | plain    |              |
 attributes                   | jsonb                          |           |          |                                                    | extended |              |
```

Comment: You have posted a number of questions recently and you are welcome. But you need to include more useful information. Postgres version, table definition, desired result. Please clarify your questions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hope that my clarification is enough. Thanks

Comment: Note that psql is the *client* program, which has its own version. You get the server version with `SELECT version()`. Typically, both are the same, but not necessarily. Also, the key sentence is unclear: `I would like to specifically names to a column, value to another column`. Did you mean: *... list the nested keys "name" and "value" as separate columns - in multiple rows.*

Comment: BTW, the question is *much* better now. If possible provide table definitions as `CREATE TABLE` statements, which allows immediate testing. (You might omit columns that are completely irrelevant to the question to reduce noise.)

Comment: The essential constraints are still missing. Is `product.product_id ` the `PRIMARY KEY`? Is there a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `order_items.product_id` to `products.product_id `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your precise objective. The query you display says you want to count identical values in the column `attributes` and list the keys "name" and "value" in separate rows for each.

This query would do that:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT COUNT(attributes) AS sayi, attributes
   FROM   order_items
   GROUP  BY attributes
   ) oi
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(attributes) a(name text, value text) ON true;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f94568783623c01c15edd2d3b6998fb1)*

Assuming that `product.product_id` the `PRIMARY KEY` and there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `order_items.product_id` to `products.product_id` - then the join to `products` is just redundant noise for this particular query. So I dropped it.

The key feature is [`jsonb_to_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).
About the unconditional `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Aside:
Look at the test setup in the fiddle to see how to best present your table definitions (including constraints!) and values.

Comment: This is almost what I needed. LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(attributes) a(name text, value text) ON true; was what I am looking for. Thanks